# Delete child objects when updating a parent Object

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working on a Django project where the admins can add pricelists to contracts via uploading a CSV file (contract is parent and pricelist is the child object(s))

When a new pricelist arrives I'd like the admin interface to delete all the old child objects and create new ones.

I have tried raw sql and the delete() option, but I haven't been able to update parent -> delete all children -> create new child objects.

Comment: @catherine user is asking for the action which needs to be done when model is updated so there is a need of [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) or [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) signal

Comment: @AamirAdnan oh sorry just a quick comment. I've read it again